# How to show comments dynamically like Stack overflow using Asp.net and Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, angularjs

I made one small web application using Asp.net and C#, I can get the comments by refreshing the entire page. But I don't want to show like that.

**For example**

There are **Client A,B,C**. All are in same page. When Client A do comment for the post, It has to appear on Client B and C with out refreshing, Exactly same like Stackoverflow

What kind of thing I should use for this Technics. Thanks

Comment: Research WebSockets and Server Sent Events

Answer (score 2):

You should use [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) library based on websocket technology
And [SQLDependency](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12335/Using-SqlDependency-for-data-change-events) to trigger db changes